# How to use Pandas dataframes API with Spark dataframes without using toPandas method?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wish to use Pandas library API (plotting, indexing) with Spark dataframes.
In Pyspark ,`df.toPandas()` , where  `df` is Spark SQL dataframe, this method will **pull the entire Spark dataframe in local memory**, thus defeating the purpose of Spark's distributed computing framework. Thus `toPandas()` method is inefficient.

I looked at other python libraries like **SparklingPandas** and **Blaze**, that try to integrate Pandas with Spark dataframes while keeping the data distributed. But they are incompatible with Spark2.x or they have no proper documentation or they are no contributions or latest version releases.

I desperately want to work with Spark but I also want to use the Pandas Dataframes API. **Spark dataframes(Spark 2.2) does not have enough features as that of Pandas.**

Answer (score 2):

> Spark dataframes(Spark 2.2) does not have enough features as that of Pandas.

They don't have enough features because scaling out requires severe trade-offs. Many features (like plotting or indexing you'd like to have) don't make much sense or would impose severe performance penalty with larger than memory and distributed data.

You just have to get over the fact, that to be able to scale, you have to give up some functionalities.

Comment: So there is no way to use Pandas dataframes on distributed systems like Spark.